# How to invert the direction of an arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, chemfig

How can I write the following diagram: A to B to C and then I want an arrow from D to B where D is below B. The following code fix the B at the bottom but I want the reverse (the command \arrow(xx1--@bb) doesn't work)

I tried with this but idk what should I change. Also, how can I type a word over or below the arrow?

```
\schemestart
A\arrow(aa--bb)B\arrow(--cc)C
\arrow(@bb--xx1)[90]X
\schemestop
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Welcome! Can you please edit your code to make it compilable?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass arguments to the `\arrow` command to draw it backwards, as well as to write text above and below the arrow. (See [documentation IV Reaction Schemes 9 Arrow optional arguments](http://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
%   \schemedebug{true}
    \schemestart
    A \arrow(aa--bb){->[up][down]} B \arrow(--cc) C
    \arrow(@bb--dd){<-}[-90]D
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My proposal is to use (for example) `tikz-cd` (it is similar to `tikz-arrows`) or `xy` package. To invert the direction of an arrow, you can write into `[...]`, `l` (left) instead of `r` (right); or `u` (up) with down `d`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=.7cm, column sep=1cm]
\mathrm{A} \arrow[r, "\text{above}", "\text{below}"'] & \mathrm{B} \arrow[r] & \mathrm{C} \\
 & \mathrm{D} \arrow[u] &  
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```